# What is $\oplus$ in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I always thought that $\oplus$ was an operator meaning "xor" in logic. Maybe it does, but how does it work for sets? I've got a question on an assignment due in an hour that asks me to define the set $A\oplus B^{c}$ where

$$\begin{align}U=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\\A=\{3,4,5,6\}\\B=\{1,3,5,7\}\end{align}$$

I only know of the intersect, union, and compliment operators currently. Not sure why he's asking this question when I don't recall him mentioning this at all in class.

Comment: I tend to think your understanding of "xor" is correct, considering the example given.

Comment: "a xor b" would probably mean items in either a or b but not in both (by definition, xor is (a\b)u(b\a)).

Comment: I sort of agree with @Tunococ, though in set theory, it is usually called *symmetric difference*, and denoted with the symbol $\triangle$.

Comment: This is a good example of why it is desirable to begin assignments well before the deadline, so that questions about notations/definitions/etc. can be asked with sufficient time left over to understand the concept once a clarification is received.

Comment: If this was in a course on algebra, the book/instructor might have wanted to emphasize the "ring" structure of sets, and hence chose $\oplus$ for that reason. (In turning a "Boolean algebra" into a "Boolean ring," the symmetric difference is the additive function of the ring...)

Comment: This site is not here to answer questions like “What does some_mathematical_term mean”. See the asking-help, in particular, “Search, and research”. If you search and find a definition on a reputable site that you cannot understand, by all means explain why and ask for an explanation. @PJTraill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation is often denoted by $\triangle$ and called [*symmetric difference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), i.e.
$$
A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)=\{x: (x\in A)\oplus (x\in B)\}.
$$

Comment: Wikipedia shows "Symmetric Difference" using $\ominus$ though, as an alternative - not $\oplus$.

Comment: Yes, but it also shows a definition using $\oplus$ (the right-most definition in my answer), and hence this _could_ be what your lecturer meant.